# Should Community’s profile page say "Hi, I'm not really a person.”?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page, community-user, user-labels

The first few words in [Community's profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1) are

> Hi, I'm not really a person.

Should these be removed?

#### Arguments I can think of for removing.

It’s redundant, the [bot] label is quite visible, and probably can’t be easily missed (I don’t think it would be affected by banner blindness, though it might be).

#### Arguments I can think of against removing

- [Tradition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRdfX7ut8gw)
- The change is too unimportant

#### Tl;dr

Should the part of communities profile page saying it’s a bot be removed, because of the new label that says community is a bot?

Comment: What's a "bot"?

Comment: Why exactly is it being redundant an argument for removing it? What does it matter?

Comment: What about people who don't know what "Bot" means? Sure, there's the tooltip, but *lots* of people don't look for, or look at, tooltips/hover text.

Comment: You don't mess with tradition 

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Does your profile need a "Hi, I'm not really a dog" label to clarify?

Comment: I don't understand your question 

Comment: @Ollie wouldn't that be what's known as a "lie"?

Comment: Given that the rest of the profile is written in the first person, I think it's necessary for it to be very clear that it's not actually a person talking.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why...

1. I do think there are many people on SE that don't know English well, and "bot" could sound misleading for them...
2. There is nothing wrong with feeding extra information to users...

One thing I do want to say is that the Community User has the Not A Robot badge, which is quite (very) misleading.

Comment: The Not a Robot badge, that's definitely where the part reminding people Community's not a person comes in handy...

Comment: ...but it *is* good to have fun.

Comment: On MSE it doesn't have the badge, but it has [awarded 380 bounties, totalling over 62K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=bounties&sort=offered);  clarifying that the account is automated and unmanned most of the time is helpful.

Answer (score 7):

A mistake that folks make is they take "At Stack Exchange, we hate fun" a little too seriously. Folks want perfect, serious rigid order and that's... boring.

A little frivolity never hurt anyone. Much like how Community has a Not A Robot badge, things like this bring a little levity to the proceedings.

I do realise folks want everything nice and neat and serious... but there's space for things not so.